# navigator.mediaDevices is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, networking, runtime-error, webrtc

So I've made a WebRTC screen sharing app as a self-hosted alternative to Chrome Remote Desktop and other common remote desktop / game streaming services.

My dilemma isn't `navigator.mediaDevices undefinded`. Whenever I launch the app over a ***`file:///`*** scheme it works perfectly; *the same* with ***`https://`*** as mentioned within Mozilla's docs. But the problem is I don't want to host it as it has a few major security issue(***s***). So how would I host it on `192.168.XXX.XXXX` without it giving the error? (*I would like to host it on my local network so I can test it on other mobile devices.*)

Comment: did you achieve it using a mobile device and connecting it to the host via lan network in 192.168.xxx.xxx?? I can't make it work since i don't know how to secure it in safari or other mobile browsers

Comment: I eventually gave up on this project for other reasons, but I retried it using the answers below and it worked perfectly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964352/11849788

Comment: 'My dilemma isn't navigator.mediaDevices undefinded.' Then why is your question navigator.mediaDevices undefinded'? It's misleading for those who actually have 'navigator.mediaDevices undefinded'

Answer (score 73, accepted):

APIs with functions like `getUserMedia`, `getDisplayMedia` and `enumerateDevices` require a [secure context](//heycam.github.io/webidl/#SecureContext), access to these from `http:` origins has been [removed in Chrome back in 2019](//groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/SGWYHfR5CyY/uyUBJZAqBwAJ)

<s>For development, the easiest solution may be to create a self-signed certificate.</s>

--UPDATE--

For development the easiest solution is to run from localhost, as that's considered secure - see https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/camera-microphone-require-https-in-firefox-68/ and https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/#localhost

Comment from: [Vlad Dinulescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855579/vlad-dinulescu)

Comment: Actually, for development the easiest solution it to run from http://localhost, as that's considered secure -  see https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/camera-microphone-require-https-in-firefox-68/ and https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/#localhost

Answer (score 41):

in mozilla developer
go to `about:config`
set to true `media.devices.insecure.enabled`  and `media.getusermedia.insecure.enabled`

Comment: The answer I've accepted is technically correct, but this one is very useful for rapid prototyping. I would recommend this if you are unable to host on localhost like the above answer.

Comment: MilkyDeveloper  - you can't use your localhost server on other devices

Comment: I was losing my mind for a while trying `about:config` in Chrome and Brave, but that page only seems to exist in Firefox.

Comment: In Google Chrome go to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`

Comment: Is there a way to get getdisplaymedia working in insecure mode? I wanted to test out a feature locally and it is not possible since getdisplaymedia is not available via http

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with firefox using the local network port. I decided to test as **localhost** instead **192.168.100.4** and it worked:

```
[Vue] App running at: 
   - Location: http://localhost:5000/ #works
   - Network: http://192.168.100.4:5000/ #error
```

Same problem on [chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663961/cannot-read-property-getusermedia-of-undefined-over-https/76546342#76546342)