# cannot read property 'getusermedia' of undefined over https

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I have a react application that should record audio from microphone and send it to a backend.
The microphone input is implemented with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia. The page runs perfectly over localhost and from other devices in my wifi network(for that I had to start my react app with https).
But when I test it with this website: http://appsimulator.net/webapp/?frame=apple_iphone_6_v, I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined.
I don't know why it is not possible to test the app over this site.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is answered directly in the [MDN documentation for `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia):

> **Note:** If the current document isn't loaded securely, `navigator.mediaDevices` will be `undefined`, and you cannot use `getUserMedia()`. See [Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#security) for more information on this and other security issues related to using `getUserMedia()`.

AppSimulator.net is not presented securely, so this call will always fail in the manner you observed. Serve the page over HTTPS.

Answer (score 9):

I got this error using the local network port. I decided to test as **localhost** instead **192.168.100.4** and it worked:

```
[Vue] App running at: 
   - Location: http://localhost:5000/ #works
   - Network: http://192.168.100.4:5000/ #error
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why ? and any workaround for using over IP ?

Comment: If you cannot load the website securely, it is possible to use a browser flag to treat the origin as secure. Go to the URL chrome://flags, search for "Insecure origins treated as secure", change it to "Enabled", type the URL of the site in the provided textbox, and restart Chrome. This must be done for every different computer or browser on which you decide to use the otherwise insecure site, but it worked well for me.