# Cannot turn on start camera app runs on remote server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, hosting, getusermedia

**The Problem**

I have a simple app with an HTML page with embedded Js served by nodejs. I use it to test Media functionality on the browser (camera).

When I run the app on my local and browse the page on localhost:8000, I can see the camera starting on and the video stream added to the page.

When I host the same app hosted AWS (Windows 2019), I can browse the page and see the markup but have the following error, and therefore no video stream is added on the page.

The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia')` pointing to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`. I recently deployed a chat app I built on the server but can't get the video to start. I created this simple app to test and used js sample from [mozzilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices).

Below are the files for my app, haven't included the `package.josn` as it has 0 dependencies.

**The App**

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Media Test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Media Test</h1>
    <p>Testing video and mic of browser.</p>
    <p id="errorMsg"></p>
    <video></video>
    <script>
        'use strict';

        // Put variables in global scope to make them available to the browser console.
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        var constraints = window.constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: true
        };
        var errorElement = document.querySelector('#errorMsg');

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then(function (stream) {
                var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
                console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
                console.log('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
                stream.onremovetrack = function () {
                    console.log('Stream ended');
                };
                window.stream = stream; // make variable available to browser console
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => { video.play() })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                if (error.name === 'ConstraintNotSatisfiedError') {
                    errorMsg('The resolution ' + constraints.video.width.exact + 'x' +
                        constraints.video.height.exact + ' px is not supported by your device.');
                } else if (error.name === 'PermissionDeniedError') {
                    errorMsg('Permissions have not been granted to use your camera and ' +
                        'microphone, you need to allow the page access to your devices in ' +
                        'order for the demo to work.');
                }
                errorMsg('getUserMedia error: ' + error.name, error);
            });

        function errorMsg(msg, error) {
            errorElement.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';
            if (typeof error !== 'undefined') {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Node Js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);

const PORT = 9000;

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/media-test.html")
})

server.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log("listening on *:", PORT)
})
```

I was initially thinking security groups and firewall rules (is a windows machine), but I have added inbound and outbound security rules and groups for TCP and UDP. Also, I can reach the app and the page is served.

Answer (score 0):

I found out media devices on remote connections over HTTP are disabled, HTTPS is required.

[navigator.mediaDevices is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957829/navigator-mediadevices-is-undefined)

[How to access Camera and Microphone in Chrome without HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759992/how-to-access-camera-and-microphone-in-chrome-without-https)

To test my remotely deployed code accessing it from my machine, I have temporarily added an exception on chrome allowing media devices over the insecure connection for the specific IP address and port. That solved my issue regarding testing the app. A long-term solution would be to install a certificate on my app and have it accessed securely over HTTPS.

Comment: You can, at least for the purpose of demo and test, host your app at heroku or glitch. You'll use their certs, and deployment is quite easy.

Comment: Great idea! I have three apps running on Heroku and never thought of testing it there. Thanks for the advice.